# Thingsboard Rule Engine and storing data in DB

Tags: database, postgresql, rules, thingsboard

I have just started using TB for about a week. I have installed TB in Ubuntu 20.04 with postgresql DB. Created dashboard with dummy data and also real data from sensor attached to Raspberry Pi.

The dashboard is showing telemetry data fine. But my question is how to store these data to Postgresql DB, tables? Seems there is option in Rule Engine to direct the data to DB, but how the Rule Engine node will identify which device is sending what data. There could be many devices under one customer/tenant. And in DB, which table? Would like to see past data from DB (say months or years).

Searched net for sometime, but didn't get any concrete information. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be looking at the DB tables at all. Do everything through the Thingsboard Dashboards. If "The dashboard is showing telemetry data fine" then that data is in the DB. The dashboard widgets pull from the DB. Rule engine knows what device is posting data because the device is the 'Originator' of the event.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I was confused when looking for TB database and its tables. I was taking data from Monday (Feb. 14) from DHT22 sensor (temp+hum) and one with just code-produced. When I check with History data, they are all there. So realized that it is storing in DB. So, to check past data, I have to change it from widgets? But if I want to analyze them, I have to transfer them to Kafka or some other external platform?

Comment: Related to Rule Engine: So Rule Engine's [Input] is forwarding all incoming messages from all the connected devices/gw etc. and depending on the Rule Node and Rule Chain msgs are forwarded to the next Node.  I was wondering if HEX Text string can be converted to JSON in Rule Engine with js? Any idea/hints?

Comment: The use case you described there is where Professional Edition data converters would come in. They can take a HEX input and produce a thingsboard friendly JSON output. If you don't want to pay for PE you can do the conversion in a cloud computing environment such as AWS lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and related information. I have actually wrote a script in javascript and using Rule Chain could convert the HEX string data to JSON. I have seen that TB's PE edition some some conversion function. Heard about lambda but never used it before, so don't know in details. Will surely check it out.